# Search inside a Mongoose model with node.js and express.js

Tags: node.js, express, find, schema, mongoose

In mongoose I've got this model:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,   
  following: [String],
  followers: [String]

}); 

var UserModel =  db.model('UserModel', userschema);
```

But I don't know who search, inside a user, search inside the following and followers array. Easily, I can do this `UserModel.find({ user: req.session.user }, function(err, user){[...]})`
But inside that, I want to search a specific string inside the arrays `following` and `followers`. I can do it using a `for loop`, but I think if I have a lot of String inside the array, search one would be slow, or even problematic. Is posible do this?:

```
UserModel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function(err, user){

   if (err) throw err;    

     user.findOne({ following: randomstring }, function(err, nuser){

        if (err) throw err;

     });

});
```

I think that this code won't work, but maybe there is a way to do what I want without using a `for loop`. Any solution...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't call `findOne` on the `user` document instance.  What you can do instead is include the `following` field in your main `UserModel.findOne` call like this:

```
UserModel.findOne({ user: req.session.user, following: randomstring }, 
    function(err, user){ ...
```

In the callback, `user` would only be set if that user was following `randomstring`.

Of course, you can also use [`array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to easily search the array in code:

```
if (user.following.indexOf(randomstring) !== -1) {
    // user is following randomstring
}
```